# Optimizing MySQL Query inCI

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter + MySQL. I want to print the number of records against each category in a section. I have an ads table, category table and section table. This is my code :

```
foreach($categories as $category){
$query = $this->db->query(" SELECT count(*) AS total_ads from ads where categoryid = $category->id and ( status = 1 OR status = 3 ) and sectionid = $section->id");
$count_row = $query->row();
$count  = $count_row->total_ads;
}
```

Total ads is around 62138 (records).
But its taking too much time for the server to respond (around 4 secs). Is there something that can speed up this code, I mean changes to optimize.

Comment: put indexes on the where columns. [mysql-indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: So should I run CREATE INDEX on the table and then run the above code ?

Comment: Yes, the index will stay on the table. It is independent of the PHP system.

Comment: yas @noob add indexes on table . same issue i face link http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43287/query-performance-of-a-select-statement-using-where-and-not-in

Comment: One more thing, After indexing update and delete queries won't change , right?

Answer (score 1):

Try to make new index in DB:

```
CREATE INDEX cat_sec_status ON ads (categoryid, sectionid, status);
```

And change you code to this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("
    SELECT COUNT(id) AS total_ads, categoryid
    FROM ads
    WHERE categoryid IN $categorysIds
        AND sectionid = $section->id            
        AND status IN (1,3)
    GROUP BY categoryid
");

$count_row = $query->row();
```

In variable $categorysIds store all categoties IDs in format '(1,2,3,4,5)'.
You don`t need foreach with this code.

**UPDATE:**
The final code may be this:

```
// Extract categories Ids into array
$categoriesIds = array_map(function($object) {return $object->id;}, $categories);

// prepare array to SQL statement
$categoriesIdsCondition = '(' . implode(',', $catIds) . ')';

// 'Good' statuses
$enabledStatuses = array(1, 3); 
$enabledStatusesCondition = '(' . implode(',', $enabledStatuses) . ')';

// Get records count of every category
$query = $this->db->query("
    SELECT COUNT(id) AS total_ads, categoryid
    FROM ads
    WHERE categoryid IN $categoriesIdsCondition
        AND sectionid = $section->id            
        AND status IN $enabledStatusesCondition
    GROUP BY categoryid
");

// If there is any records, store them
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   $adsCounter = $query->result();
}

// Usage example
foreach($adsCounter as $categoryAds){
    echo "In the category with ID = 
        . {$categoryAds->categoryid}
        . there are
        . {$recordsCounter->total_ads}
        . records";
}
```